# What is the specific meaning of phrase "bottom line" here

Tags: meaning

“Managers need to realize that investing in better ways of hiring, scheduling and managing employees is an investment in the company’s bottom line,” Ostrega added.

Does that mean the same as "investing in better ways of hiring, scheduling and managing employees is an investment in future success of the company?"
or "will generate profits"
or "must be priority of the company"

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bottom-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line may  refer to the final net results in the  financial statements of a company or any action that may have an impact on it. In yours sentence it is used with the second meaning:

[Bottom line](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bottomline.asp):

> - Refers to a company's net earnings, net income or earnings per share (EPS).
> - Bottom line also refers to any actions that may increase/decrease net earnings or a company's overall profit. A company that is growing its net earnings or reducing its costs is said to be "improving its bottom line".

(Incestpedia.com)

Comment: Refers should be *refer*. Balance Sheet is different from Income Statement.

Comment: Why *refer*?...